# Как сделать, чтобы при каждом обновление хита сайта менялась картинка?

Tags: html, css, php

Я сделал сайт на HTML + css+php. Дал ссылку как `<img>`. У меня два рисунка, которые должны чередоваться при обновлении. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать это?

Comment: Чередоваться в случайном порядке или строго один за другим?

Answer (score 1):

Создайте переменную в `$_SESSION, $_COOKIE, $_GET, localStorage`, - в общем там, где Вам удобно, в которой будет хранится номер картинки, которую надо выводить пользователю. В первых трех случаях формировать адрес картинки может PHP, в трех последних случаях JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Вывод случайной картинки из заданного набора:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = [],
    index = 0;

    images[0] = "<img src='image1.jpg'>";
    images[1] = "<img src='image2.jpg'>";

    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

    document.write(images[index]);
</script>
```